# How to dynamically load HTTP routing into NGINX from your webframework?

Tags: python, http, web-applications, nginx, routes

I've been following the [Web Frameworks Benchmark](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/) and have noticed that a number of web framework suffer from the same performance penalty, that being they do HTTP routing ***within*** the framework itself and not leverage the highly performant HTTP server of NGINX to do routing.

For example, in the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) python framework, you might have:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    ...
```

Which makes your application much easier to follow than doing it directly within NGINX *config* file like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /add {
        ... // defer to Flask (python) app
    }
```

**Question**: How can you gain the performance of NGINX built-in HTTP routing (using NGINX own config file to define routing), while also keeping the easy of application development by defining the HTTP routing within your web framework?

Is there a way you can dynamically load into NGINX from INSERT_NAME_OF_YOUR_WEBFRAMEWORK the HTTP routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a ready to use library. But it seems pretty easy to write a script, which generates an Nginx config file from application's routes (for example, during application setup). This file can be included into main configuration of server using "include" command of Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    include /path/to/application/routes.conf
}
```

Comment: I guess, it's needed in production environment only, where efficiency matters. Therefore it's not a problem to restart Nginx during deployment of new version of application.

Comment: There is a way to reload nginx config without restarting the whole server: http://serverfault.com/questions/108261/how-to-make-modification-take-affect-without-restart-nginx

Comment: Keep in mind that Flask allows for specifying which HTTP verb (POST, GET, etc), regular expressions in the URL, retrieving variables from the query string (e.g. '/user/<username>' and now 'username' is Python defined variable equal to the query string value), etc... So unless someone as already accounted for these use case, this is non-trivial to start from scratch